# Jenkins Build failed - Sonar Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, findbugs

After updating Sonar from 5.1 to 5.2 the Jenkins-Build failed.
My Jenkins Sonar-Plugin is version 2.3 and the Maven-Plugin 2.6 (I tried also 2.7.1 but it failed too).
I use Maven 3.0.4 and Jenkins 1.629. 
Here is my error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project module.fakturierung: org.sonar.api.resources.Project.getPom()Lorg/apache/maven/project/MavenProject; -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project module.fakturierung: org.sonar.api.resources.Project.getPom()Lorg/apache/maven/project/MavenProject;
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: org.sonar.api.resources.Project.getPom()Lorg/apache/maven/project/MavenProject;
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.api.resources.Project.getPom()Lorg/apache/maven/project/MavenProject;
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsMavenInitializer.getExcludesFiltersFromPluginConfiguration(FindbugsMavenInitializer.java:57)
    at org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsMavenInitializer.execute(FindbugsMavenInitializer.java:52)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.InitializersExecutor.execute(InitializersExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.executeInitializersPhase(PhaseExecutor.java:156)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:87)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:258)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:253)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:251)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:243)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:100)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeAnalysis(GlobalContainer.java:153)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:110)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:76)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :module.fakturierung
```

Has anyone an idea or a solution?

Comment: Which version of Jenkins? Which Version of Maven do you use?

Comment: Jenkins is version 1.629 and Maven 3.0.4

Comment: What is the version of sonar-findbugs you are using ? I would recommend to use the latest version .

Comment: Oh okay...i watched and is version an old version. I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it works, after updating Findbugs on version 3.3! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the log fragment:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.sonar.api.resources.Project.getPom()Lorg/apache/maven/project/MavenProject;
at 
org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsMavenInitializer.getExcludesFiltersFromPluginConfiguration(FindbugsMavenInitializer.java:57)
```

I guess your problem is related to the SonarQube embedded Findbugs plugin: you might find useful [SonarQube embedded Findbugs plugin compatibility](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/FindBugs+Plugin#FindBugsPlugin-Compatibility).

Comment: It was exactly the Sonarqube Findbugs Plugin. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, what did you do to fix this?